# International Trade Issues

Tags: import, export

As a co-founder of a start-up company which is often involved in dealing with buyers which are located in different countries, I was wondering if there is any platform from which me and my company can facilitate from so that we could communicate with our vendors and buyers conveniently. Are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Morrawat Shamsi, Marketing Manager of Trade Ally International. We are a US based Import and Export company. I believe we can help you in your trading activities. Why don't you check out our website so you can see for yourself if we can offer you what you need. Its www.tradeallyint.com. Remember, we offer our membership for FREE for 3 months! And we will extend it for you if either you do extensive trade through our website or if you are unable to trade on our platform due to inadequate number of trading partners available on our website. So it's really a win win for you. Can't hurt to have a free premium membership right?
Oh, and if you have any questions, please feel free to contact us via any of the following methods:
1. FB - https://www.facebook.com/TradeAllyInternational
2. Contact Us form on our website
3. Call at +1 (224) 330 1144
We look forward to having you as a member on our platform.

Comment: Thank you for attending to my problem instantly. I will definitely look into it.